# Modify authorization for registry by code

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# application and I'm trying to set authorization for all the local users for a registry.

There is my code :

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32);
RegistryKey vkey = key.OpenSubKey("Software\\MyApplication", true);
if (vkey == null)
{
    session.Log("Software\\MyApplication" + " is null : create it");
    vkey = key.CreateSubKey("Software\\MyApplication", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
}

RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
rs = vkey.GetAccessControl();
SecurityIdentifier secu = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-2-0");
NTAccount name = secu.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;                
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(name.ToString(), RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

After that the registry is rightly created but with the wrong authorization.

[image]

I want to set authorization to check this box (Contrôle Total = Full control) :

[image]

**EDIT**:

I did a test :

- get the `AuthorizationRuleCollection`
- set the authorisation manually
- get the `AuthorizationRuleCollection`
- compare both

There I found that a new rule has been added for "S-1-5-32-545" with acces mask 0x000F003F. There I programmatically do the change. There is my code :

```
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
rs = vkey.GetAccessControl();
SecurityIdentifier secu = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-545");
NTAccount name = secu.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;                
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(name.ToString(), RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

When I get the `AuthorizationRuleCollection` I saw that a new rule has been added. But after the programm ends, there is no change in the registry.

How can I validate/flush my modification ?

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  Applications should not do this, as it will lead to security risks.  There's a reason that users don't have permissions to the HKLM registry key, and your application should *NOT* change that.

Comment: But my application use a service. This service named "MyApplication" use the registry. If I don't get full control to users, this service can not start.

Comment: No service should be modifying the HKLM registry.  That's for machine-level configurations which should be read-only at run-time.  If you want to set a particular setting during execution for all users, then do it under the default key under HKEY_USERS.

Comment: I'm not the developer for this service. I can't modify it. The only I have to use it is by modify the access for registry.

Comment: Well, if you're taking this approach, why not just let everyone run under the administrator account? You're ignoring all the security advice anyway, so why bother with complicated workarounds? In any case, there's many layers to registry virtualization. Read the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx.